# Tabulating and visualizing the expression 0.905*(0.1^n)/n!

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I need help tabulating and visualizing the expression, `0.905*0.1^n)/n!`, where n goes from 0 to 100.

I want to store all the values, and use those values to plot a histogram.

I have used `NsolveValues[{(0.905*0.1^n)/n!}]`, but am having issues extracting the data and then using that data to draw a histogram. Please help? I am a beginner so help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please write a short descriptive title and describe the problem you face in the post body itself. Include enough Mathematica code in copy-paste-able form so that respondents can replicate your problem. The word `Dataset` has specialized meaning in Mathematica. As a starting point, you can explore the `Table` command. You can edit your post by clicking on the `Edit` link under your post and format code using the `{  }` icon once you are in the Edit window. Thanks.

Comment: `NDSolveValue` is a command for differential equations. What you have provided is not. Is it possible that you forgot to copy some terms in your expression?

Comment: Table command worked, thanks! would appreciate help in plotting the histogram.

Comment: You should look up [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)

Comment: @NarenViswanathanNarenKumar and since I had a look at the data generated by the expression you gave -it's not an equation- I think you will find [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) very useful

Answer (score 8):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = Table[{n, 0.905*0.1^n/n!}, {n, 0, 100}];
```

Looking at the first elements of the data list

```
data[[;; 4]]

(* {{0, 0.905}, {1, 0.0905}, {2, 0.004525}, {3, 0.000150833}} *)
```

There are several ways to plot the data or the function

```
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[0.905*0.1^n/n!, {n, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[0.905*0.1^n/n!, {n, 0, 100},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot[0.905*0.1^n/n!, {n, 0, 100},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I like your creativity and imagination. You demonstrated many useful ways of presenting the data. Out of curiosity, why didn't you do the histogram?

Comment: @bmf - I didn't consider a histogram an appropriate way to reflect the data or the function.

Comment: Neither did I, but the author wanted that for some reason. That's why I asked. In any case, nicely done!!!

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 4):

Check out the answer by @Bob Hanlon for various pictorial representations of the data generated by your expression. Make sure to upvote it as well!!!

Below I am showing you a histogram.

```
data = Table[(0.9050 .1^n)/n!, {n, 0, 100}] // Chop[#, 10^-5] &;
```

The above generates data from the expression given and [`Chops`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) numbers that are $10^{-5}$.

You can check your data

```
data
```

> `{0.905, 0.0905, 0.004525, 0.000150833, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

In order to get a [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)

```
Histogram[data]
```

[image: histo]